# MKMapView has warning (VKBuildingFootprintTileSource)

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

While testing my app on an old iPad (using iOS 9.4), this message appears:

" *wants grid size 64.000000, min display z: 13, min download z: 16. This is probably a bug!*"

This doesn't appear on the iOS 11 simulator.

Am I using code that is not correct? Should this be reported as a bug?

This is a pretty simple map - I set the delegate to self and have a pin at a certain location.

Why do I receive this message?